# Jenkins build issue - npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am trying to build a small node app on my Jenkins pipeline, which is running in a virtual machine. cross this error:

```
    + npm install
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 111:120 "/.npm"
```

Running `sudo chown -R 111:120 "/.npm"` doesn`t help since it says:

> chown: cannot access '/.npm': No such file or directory

And, as per my understanding, runs in a local context, when the problem is actually from the container perspective. I`ve tried to add the command above on my Docker and Jenkinsfile as well, to no avail. Below is my public repo:

[Node app deploy on github](https://github.com/amxwesley/docker)

Comment: Try by cleaning the cache once `sudo npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Should I add it to Jenkinsfile after invoking the Shell? @SouravAtta

Comment: invoke in shell and then try to run execute jenkinsfile

Comment: @SouravAtta it says:

npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.24.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: The same command fixed the same issue for me. So, I thought to share the answer with you. But it looks like there is something else.

Comment: I had this issue because I had a `--user x` override in the `docker run` command. Omitting that resulted in the default `node` user being used, which resolved the issue. Using the default `node:20` package

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As far as I can remember ,just updating npm version and deleting the whole project did the trick.

Answer (score 19):

```
npm install --cache=".YourCustomCacheDirectoryName"
```

works perfectly fine, reason for this is your docker user isn't allowed to write in / ( root directory )
its not that a directory already exist at /.npm its that, your script is trying to create a directory at / which is not accessible for your user
you can either put

```
agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:latest'
      args '-u root:root'
    }
}
```

or just tell npm to use your custom cache directory

Comment: Kindly mark this as answer if it solved your problem, so others can take benefit from it as well

Comment: I think you'll need to ping @wes85melis directly

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `args '-u root:root'` ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by setting the npm cache directory to ENV variable in Dockerfile.

Add this to Dockerfile:

```
ENV npm_config_cache /home/node/app/.npm
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be running the official `node` docker image with a different user than the default `node` user. You might have overridden it in the Dockerfile or with the `docker run --user x` parameter.

I just upgraded from `node:16` to `node:20` and started having this issue. Removing `--user someuser` or setting it to `node` fixed the issue.